# Conversion of milliseconds duration to ISO 8601 precise string format for duration in Java

Tags: java

I want to convert duration in milliseconds to ISO 8601 precise interval format : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

I can find code example for conversion the other way around. Are there standard Java library support to it from milliseconds to appropriate string format?

Comment: How is this off-topic? Asking to generate an ISO 8601 string of a duration in milliseconds is specific, clear, and can be answered directly (as seen in both correct answers already posted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
String iso = Duration.ofMillis(millis).toString();
```

[`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) returns the duration using the **ISO-8601** seconds based representation

Answer (score 5):

The [`Duration#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) method returns

> A string representation of this duration using ISO-8601 seconds based
>   representation, such as `PT8H6M12.345S`.

Use any of the various factory methods to create a `Duration` instance, then invoke its `toString` method to get a proper representation.